# how to append the value to array in elasticsearch java api

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch

i have an ES document which contains an array as well

```
{"uuid":"123","userList":["1","2"]}
```

i want to update userList array and add another element like "3" in `elasticsearch 1.6` i did it something like this and it worked

```
client.prepareUpdate(indexName, typename, uuid)
            .setScript("ctx._source.userList += '" + value + "'", ScriptService.ScriptType.INLINE))
```

but now i upgraded to elasticsearch 7.1 and now i am trying it to do something like this but i am not getting it worked

```
val updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(ARTGROUP_INDEX_NAME,artGroupUuid)
val fieldName = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE,"painless", "ctx._source.userList",scala.collection.mutable.Map(fieldNameStr -> value))
          updateRequest.script(fieldName)
```

here the value type is `Any` not `object`

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Map[String,Any]    (in scala.collection.mutable) 
[error]  required: Map[String,Object] (in java.util)
```

how can i use it here also will this way work?